# Meaning of 無理して

Tags: meaning

> A：でも、おおやまさん、いきたくないのに、どうしていくんですか。**むりして**いかなくてもいいじゃないですか。
>
> B：そうおもって、いちど、いかなかったんです。そしたら、しんじんなのになまいきだっていわれました。しんじんはつくらなきゃいけないって、しかられました。
>
> A：ふうん、そうなんですか。

What's the meaning of "むりして" and I don't understand the answer of B person

> そうおもって、いちど、いかなかったんです。そしたら、しんじんなのになまいきだっていわれました。しんじんはつくらなきゃいけないって、しかられました。

Answer (score 2):

無理して is the te-form of [無理する](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%84%A1%E7%90%86), "to try too hard", "to overwork", "to do (something) forcibly", "to go out of one's way", etc.

> 無理【むり】して行【い】かなくてもいいじゃないですか?
>   You don't have to go out of your way to go there, do you?

---

(Regarding the meaning of B's response, please edit your question and specify your problem. As of now, it's just a translate-it-for-me question.)

Answer (score -1):

無理して: do something involuntarily.  He (or she) had given up in his (her) mind.  However, usually it is not he that decides if it is able to do in Japanese society but anyone else who has an upper role than he.  It was bad habits and recently Japanese young persons have begun to **reject** what they cannot do because they are awakened by the results which is not so good neither for themselves nor for other persons.